# Sample with replacement in python with limit on number of samples from each class

Tags: python, numpy

Python has `random.choices`, which lets you sample from a population with replacement, assigning different weights to different members of the population.  Similarly, numpy has `np.random.choice` which is similar (though it annoyingly forces you to normalize your weights into a probability distribution).  But neither function allows you to restrict how many times each member of the population can occur in the sample.  This is necessary if the members represent subpopulations and you are doing hierarchical sampling where you want to sample the members of each subpopulation without replacement since otherwise you might choose a subpopulation more times than it has members.  Is there some other library function that can do this?

Comment: You seem to have identified the problem: sampling *with* replacement vs sampling *without* replacement. The same `numpy` function seems to support both with `replace` option. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html.  Providing an example with code would help clarify your specific request.

Comment: Sampling without replacement is like sampling with the limit on the number of samples from each member of the population set to 1.  Sampling with replacement is like having the limit be infinity.  What I need is to be able to set the limit to any positive integer for each member of the population.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a function specifically for that, the requirement is a little unusual. You can use NumPy to repeat each member of a population some number of times in a new population to be sampled without replacement:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
weights = [.2, .5, .2, .1]
replace_limits = [8, 2, 4, 10]

repeated_x = np.repeat(x, replace_limits)
new_weights = np.repeat(weights, replace_limits)
new_weights /= np.sum(new_weights)

sample = np.random.choice(repeated_x, size=10, replace=False, p=new_weights)
```

This isn't the most memory-efficient option, but that would require writing the algorithm in a lower-level language.

Comment: Thanks.  I would actually need to divide the weights by the replace limits and then repeat them so that each class would still have the same weight.

Doing that, it seems like this would be reasonable expecially for cases where the limits are typically low. My case is kind of in the opposite regime where what I want is almost like sampling with replacement, but sometimes there need to be limits because there are not enough elements in the subpopulation to sample, the memory blowup would be almost quadratic, but it might be OK since my arrays aren't too big.

Comment: Not to rag on my own answer but a nuance just occurred to me. In sampling without replacement, ignoring an already sampled member is equivalent to setting its weight to 0 and redistributing the weight to the other members. My method copies each member, so each time a copy is used up, the other copies' weights change. On the other hand, you might have wanted the member's weight to remain unchanged until hitting the replacement limit and sharply going to 0 instead of gradually with each copy. This nuance is probably why a version of sampling that does what you ask for isn't readily available.

Comment: In my application, this gradual decrease in your algorithm is actually better, though the difference isn't very important to me.  I was actually originally thinking about the distribution you get by taking sampling with replacement and then conditioning on the limits being respected.  Which I think is what you mean by the dropping suddenly to zero option.